# Wordpress Responsie Theme feature image not showing fully

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I hae created a website and i haev set a blog with featured images but the images dont show full it just shows half of it even if i change it in css it still shows half.

[image: as you can see his head is not showing]

can anyone help me please

Comment: Try at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Where the image is shown in code:

```
// has_post_thumbnail() - boolean
get_the_post_thumbnail($id, $size, $attr ) // gets any thumbnail

the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ) // for use inside the loop
// demand a custom featured image size on upload for a custom post type.
add_image_size( 'review_type', 245, 245, true);
// call that size
the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ) // for use inside the loop
```

When uploaded in the media library you can choose the upload image size. However WP creates 3 images upon upload and fits one of them into your page. The function above can specify which image is used by "small", "medium", "large".